# Jquery image point out on mouse over within an images grid

Tags: jquery, image, plugins

Does anyone know a simple Jquery plugin or other method (always with Jquery) to get the effect to point out an image in a image grid on mouseover? I would have thought a tiny zoom effect or...somenthing else I  don't know.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty sample that uses opacity as the highlight effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/K4esU/

The principle holds, though, no matter what effect you'd like to use.  Add whatever updates you'd like into the first function in the hover and return things to normal in the second function.